# Google Sheets API throwing 401 error while append rows to spreadsheet without login

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

**Objective:** Submit a form and store data to google spreadsheet

documentation: [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)

**What I've done so far:**

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets";

var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');
 function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }
function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES
    })
function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      //authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
      //signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
      //listMajors();
    } else {
      //authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
      //signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
function update_docs(data) {
    var params = {
      spreadsheetId: '1YXMlr_-I45AWM2b9QnLkuLQoI6dq6wEuVOcttOMv9hU',
      range: 'A:I',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    };

  var valueRangeBody = {

    "range": 'A:I', // 9 cols
    "majorDimension": 'ROWS',
    "values": [
      [
        data[0].value,//nom,
        data[1].value,//prenom,
        data[2].value,//email,
        data[3].value,//user_phone,
        data[4].value,//company_name,
        data[5].value,//user_type,
        data[6].value,//account_name,
        data[7].value,//password,
        data[8].value,//comptes_sources,
      ]
    ]

  };

  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(params, valueRangeBody);
  request.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
}
```

I can successfully append rows to the spreadsheet if I'm logged in to my google account.

**Question:** Can I append row without logging in(if yes please provide some docs/code)?
Because if I submit the form from a private window it throws 401 error.

**error message:** `error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.`

Comment: In your script, it seems that you try to append rows using API key. Unfortunately, API key cannot be used for appending rows to Spreadsheet, because API key cannot be used for POST and PUT methods. Please use the access token retrieved from OAuth2 or Service account as the error message says. If this was not useful information for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I think before you start working on this you need to understand a few things.

There is a difference between private and public data.

- Public data, Searching publicly uploaded youtube videos
- Private data, My person gmail account, drive account, calendar account.

Even setting the sheet to public will not help you as with it public using an api key you will only be allowed to read the sheet not update it.

Answer: No you can not append a row without the application being authenticated and having access to the data.

Assuming that this is a sheet that you personally own you could set up a service account authenticate and grant the service account access to the sheet it will then be able to make the changes for you without you having to login.  However this depends upon how your application works and what language you are using.  I dont think that javascript supports service account authentication.

Comment: Thank for the concept. Yes javascript don't support service account authentication. Solved the issue converting from javascript to php.